# amCharts align values axis' null level

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have an Amchart graph with multiple charts and multiple value axis. Values may be quite different, for example, one chart's values may vary from -3000 to 3000, while another one is 0-40.

What I want is to represent all charts so they all will be visible. So, I use 'synchronizeGrid' option.

Here's my current code:

```
  "synchronizeGrid": true,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "axisColor": "#FF6600",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "left"
  }, {
    "id": "v2",
    "axisColor": "#FCD202",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "offset": 50,
    "position": "left"
  }, {
    "id": "v3",
    "axisColor": "#B0DE09",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "offset": 100,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "left"
  }],
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fungxbsh/

However, you may notice that null level is not the same, i.e. each chart has null level at different grid line. Is there a way to force all charts to use the same null level?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to make the three axes use the same "null" value is to simply find the maximum absolute value for each of them and set it as `maximum` and `minimum` parameters while defining the [ValueAxis](https://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis) according to the documentation of AmCharts.

So at the end, you'll have three variables to store the absolute values `maxVisits`, `maxHits`, `maxViews`.

Then you set the `maximum` and `minimum` parameters like this:

```
"valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "axisColor": "#FF6600",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "left",
    "maximum": maxVisits,
    "minimum": -maxVisits
  }, {
    "id": "v2",
    "axisColor": "#FCD202",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "maximum": maxHits,
    "minimum": -maxHits
  }, {
    "id": "v3",
    "axisColor": "#B0DE09",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "offset": 50,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "left",
    "maximum": maxViews,
    "minimum": -maxViews
  }]
```

And finally you need to set the `synchronizeGrid` parameter to `false` again.

[See the full example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/goran90/fungxbsh/2/)

Comment: This works great but does anyone know how to do this in amcharts 4?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I've come up with:

Make use of:

```
            "synchronizeWith": "v1",
            "synchronizationMultiplier": sync
```

For example, on your v2 axis, use 'synchronizeWith' and set the value to the Axis you want to sync to. For multiplier, you want to look for the max values in both axes, and divide the smaller value by the bigger value, giving you a ratio. This ratio is your multiplier.